# Creating a new map from json JsObject

Tags: scala

I have the following json string:

```
{"1342558874663000":{"TEMPERATURE_C":"253","TEMPERATURE_F":"775"},
"1342558854606000":{"TEMPERATURE_C":"254","TEMPERATURE_F":"776"}}
```

I would like to iterate though this object and create a new json object with the format:

```
{"TEMPERATURE_C":[["1342558874663000","253"], ["1342558854606000","254"]],
"TEMPERATURE_F":[["1342558874663000", "775"], ["1342558854606000","776"]]}
```

I am trying to do the following but can't quite figure out how to create the new map:

```
json.fields.foreach {
        case (epoch, obj) => {
          val newVal = obj.as[JsObject].fields.map {
            case (temps, value) => {
              Map(temps -> (epoch, value.as[String])).toMap
            }
          }
          println(newVal)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reasonably straightforward working example that produces the output you want:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val json = Json.parse("""
  {"1342558874663000":{"TEMPERATURE_C":"253","TEMPERATURE_F":"775"},
  "1342558854606000" :{"TEMPERATURE_C":"254","TEMPERATURE_F":"776"}}
""").as[JsObject]

Json.toJson(json.fields.flatMap {
  case (epoch, obj) => obj.as[JsObject].fields.map(epoch -> _)
}.groupBy(_._2._1).mapValues(
  _.map { case (epoch, (_, v)) => Seq(epoch, v.as[String]) }
))
```

The trick here is to flatten the list and then rebuild the structure you need.

Comment: Thats amazing, I need to figure out how it actually works its a bit beyond me but thanks!